# How to look for lines which don't end with a certain character

Tags: regex

How to look for lines which don't end with a ."

```
description="This has a full stop."
description="This has a full stop."
description="This line doesn't have a full stop"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a character class to describe the occurrence of any character except `.`:

```
[^\n.](\n|$)
```

This will match any character that is neither a `.` nor new line character, and that is either followed by a new line character or by the end of the string. If multiline mode is supported, you can also use just `$` instead of `(\n|$)`.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your environent. On Linux/Unix/Cygwin you would do something like this:

```
grep -n -v '\."$' <file.txt
```

or

```
grep -n -v '\."[[:space:]]*$' <file.txt
```

if trailing whitespace is fine.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the regular expression pattern you are looking for is the following:

```
\."$
```

`\.` means a real dot. (compared to . which means any character except \n)

`"` is the double quote that ends the line in your example.

`$` means end of line.

The way you will use this pattern depends on the environment you are using, so give us more precision for a more precise answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

In general, regular expression matches. It is not easy to do a don't match. The general solution for this kind of thing is to invert the truth value. For example:

grep: `grep -v '\.$'`

Perl: `$line !~ /\.$/`

Tcl: `![regexp {\.$} $line]`

In this specific case, since it is just a character, you can use the character class syntax, `[]`, since it accepts a `^` modifier to signify anything that is not the specified characters:

```
[^.]$
```

so, in Perl it would be something like:

```
$line =~ /[^.]$/
```